# Probability of 2 people guessing the number on dreidel

Tags: probability

> A dreidel has 4 equally likely outcome {1,2,3,4}, the dreidel is spinned 3 times.
>   
>   2 people are betting on different numbers, What is the possibility the will be right in 1,2,3 numbers?

Has for the 1 people it is  $P(X=1)=3*\frac{1}{4}*(\frac{3}{4})^2$  ,$P(X=2)={2\choose 3}(\frac{1}{4})^2*\frac{3}{4}$  ,$P(X=3)=(\frac{1}{4})^3$

How Should I approach if it is 2 people? Can I look at this as 1 person with 2 bets?

The answer: $P(Y=1)=\frac{6}{16}$, $P(Y=2)=\frac{6}{16}$, $P(Y=3)=\frac{2}{16}$

Comment: Just to clarify, the question is asking what the probability is that _either_ one of them will be right in each respective number of spins?

Comment: Yes, either one of them

Comment: And they are not allowed to bet on the same number?

Comment: No, they are betting on different numbers

Comment: If one person made 2 bets on two different numbers, what is the difference with two persons making one bet each on two different numbers? What I'm saying is that the bets and their probabilities don't care for who made them.

Comment: @EmilyL. So what is the case that 1 person is right in the 2 numbers and the other is right in the 2 numbers ? If it is 1 person we look at it as?

Comment: I do not understand the question as it is formulated so I will not attempt an answer. Ask your teacher or TA.

Comment: Can you please double check that you wrote out your question properly? Because as it stands, it makes no sense.